# Flexbox doesn't paginate in print view (and other problems)

Tags: css, printing, flexbox, overlap, visual-glitch

I've got a simple web page:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
  document.write("<div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. " + i * 1001 + " <hr /> The lazy brown fox quickly jumps over my dog.</div>");
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
body > div {
  page-break-after: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 2.5cm;
}
```

When you go into Print Preview, you can see that the end part of the page doesn't print at all. And if you scroll down, flexbox completely gives up on trying to make the rows work at some point.

Are these issues resolvable? If not, is there another way to create this kind of dynamic grid that doesn't have these issues? (The whole point of this is to create a printout.)